# read files with pattern in R, error

Tags: r

I have a file in my directory with multiple shapefiles (about 2000) and I want to read them in R. So far I have tried the following :

```
list.files("my_directory",pattern=".shp")
list_here=list.files("my_directory",pattern=".shp")
for (i in 1:length(list_here)){
  bi[[i]]=readShapeSpatial(list_here[i])
  proj4string(bi[[i]])= CRS("+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs")
}
```

but I get the error `Error in getinfo.shape(fn) : Error opening SHP file`

each shapefile consists of `.dbf,.prj,.shp,.shx` files. When I try to read one or two of them I have no problem but when I try to read them in list I get the aforementioned error.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: It's probably a problem with one particular file (or more). Put a `print(i)` in your loop so you can find out which one has the error.

Comment: Hi @Gregor. I have tried this but I get nothing. As soon as I run the loop I get the error and the print(i) shows nothing.

Comment: have a look into file `list_here[i]` after the loop crashed. `i` should point you to the problematic file.

Comment: If you get the error immediately before the first `print(i)`, try setting `i = 1` & execute each line within your for loop sequentially? That may give you better perspective on what's triggering the error.

Comment: have you also got `.shx` and `.dbf` files along with corresponding `.shp` file as all three are needed to make a `Shapefile`

Comment: Thank you all for your response to my problem. I tried the try: function because the print(i) gave me nothing and I found a file (1253) with a missing .prj. Problem solved now, thank you again!

Comment: The problem may be that the paths are not including the directory. There is an option for that in list.files()